# Android Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on an android app for the past few weeks or so, and I have been using firebase as my backend. I have had no trouble reading/writing from firebase, but recently, all addListenerForSingleValueEvent calls have not been triggering. I'm not exactly sure why it would suddenly just stop reading. My database rules (for testing purposes) are

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
```

and the relevant code is

```
    final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //searches database for user
    //This "LISTENING" println triggers
    System.out.println("LISTENING");
    mDatabase.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //This print statement never prints
            System.out.println("DATA SNAPSHOT");
            for(DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                for(DataSnapshot participant: user.getChildren()) {
                    //if we have found the participant name
                    if(participant.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Participant Name")){
                        System.out.println(participant.getValue().toString().trim());
                    }
                }
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("Error");

        }
    });
```

I also have several other addListenerForSingleValueEvent calls (that are similar in structure, so for brevity's sake, I wont post them here) that were working fine until about 2 hours ago. What could be going on? Could this be an issue with firebase itself? Is there something in my code I am overlooking?

Comment: Resolved- sort of. Had to use a different emulator. Unclear what the issue was.

Comment: go for addValueEventListener(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem ocured here, but i'm testing with phone (huawei y560-l01).

Edit:

I solved the problem with uninstalling the application, unplunging the device, restarting the device, and than conecting and running the code again.

Comment: Exactly..... uninstalling and reinstalling solves the problem. But this should not be the case. We can't tell every user to uninstall and reinstall the app if this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving this by switching emulators. I'm not fully sure what the exact problem was, but that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I found that the google play services version(can reference: google-play-services.en.uptodown.com/android/old) on the smartphone needs to match the firebase version declared in the dependencies. It will work not only on the emulator but also on the device(Samsung J7).

Comment: I am also facing the same problem in my j7 device, how did you overcome this issue?@Alex