# Firebase Event Listener never triggered

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I am trying to retrieve some data from Firebase, but it is not working for one of my nodes

Note that the UnverifiedEmployees node works fine but the Companies node is not
I am able to see the Log RIGHT BEFORE the Event Listener, but nothing inside of it prints
I am referring to this area:

```
public void addDataToFirebase() {

                Log.i("BEFORE", "BEFORE COMPANIES REF");
                companiesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Log.i("COMPANIESREF", "INSIDE COMPANIES REF ONDATACHANGE");
```

I have tried this on a different phone. I have tried it on wifi and 4g. I also tried logging in with a different user
I have also tried uninstalling the app from my phone and reinstalling. I have tried writing different implementations of the addListener.
I have also tried looking this up but did not find a lot (e.g. [Android Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271237/android-firebase-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent-not-called)) ( [Firebase Android addListenerForSingleValueEvent sometimes not returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703218/firebase-android-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent-sometimes-not-returning-data))

Database: (If UserID exists, grab the CompanyID its related to)

[image: Database Structure]

Entirety of Code: AddEmployeeActivity.java:

```
    public class AddEmployeeActivity extends Activity {

        private EditText firstNameET, lastNameET, phoneNumberET, emailET, ssnET;
        private ImageView checkmarkImage;

        private static FirebaseUser currentUser;
        private static final String TAG = "RealtimeDB";
        private FirebaseDatabase database;
        private DatabaseReference unverifiedRef, companiesRef;

        String emailKey, ssnKey, phoneKey, companyId;

        int num;
        private FirebaseMethods firebaseMethods;
        private Context mContext;

        ArrayList<EmployeeUser> myListItems;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_addemployees);

            mContext = AddEmployeeActivity.this;

            firstNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNameET);
            lastNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastNameET);
            phoneNumberET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberET);
            emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailET);
            ssnET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ssnET);

            checkmarkImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.checkmarkImage);

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            unverifiedRef = database.getReference("/Unverified Employees");
            companiesRef = database.getReference("/Companies");
            currentUser =
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            checkmarkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    final String email = emailET.getText().toString().trim();
                    final String ssn = ssnET.getText().toString().trim();
                    final String phone = phoneNumberET.getText().toString().trim();

                    //Add EditText info to Firebase UnverifiedEmployees Node
                    addDataToFirebase();               

                }
            });



        } //End of ONCREATE


        public void addDataToFirebase() {

            Log.i("BEFORE", "BEFORE COMPANIES REF");
            //companiesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
            companiesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.i("COMPANIESREF", "INSIDE COMPANIES REF ONDATACHANGE");

                    EmployeeUser user = new EmployeeUser();

                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds2 : ds.getChildren()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot ds3 : ds2.getChildren()) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds4 : ds3.getChildren()) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot ds5 : ds4.getChildren()) {


                                        Log.i(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: datasnapshot: " + ds5);

                                        //user.setCompanyId(ds5.getValue(EmployeeUser.class).getCompanyId());
                                        user.setCompanyId(ds5.getValue(String.class));

                                        Log.i(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: ID: " + user.getCompanyId());
                                        //callback.gotDataSnapshot(dataSnapshot);

    if (user.getCompanyId() != null) {
                                            companyId = user.getCompanyId();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.i("Cancelled", "In onCancelled: " + databaseError);

                }
            //};
            }); //END OF ADDLISTENER

           // companiesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);


            emailKey = unverifiedRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).push().getKey();
            unverifiedRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).child(emailKey).child("emailAddress").setValue(emailET.getText().toString(), completionListener);
            Log.i("getKey EMAIL", emailKey);

            ssnKey = unverifiedRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).push().getKey();
            unverifiedRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).child(ssnKey).child("socialSecurityNumber").setValue(ssnET.getText().toString(), completionListener);
            unverifiedRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).child(ssnKey).child("CompanyID").setValue(companyId, completionListener);
            Log.i("getKey SSN", ssnKey);
            Log.i("get COMPANY ID", companyId);

            phoneKey = unverifiedRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).push().getKey();
            unverifiedRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).child(phoneKey).child("phoneNumber").setValue(phoneNumberET.getText().toString(), completionListener);
            Log.i("getKey Phone", phoneKey);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this in the way you do. There is no way in which you can get a parent based on the value of one of its childs. With other words, you cannot get the value of `L4bs8bH5...` if that id `RC9zI1...` exists beneath it. To solve this, you need to consider using denormalization, which is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. This means that you need to duplicate data in order have those results. For that, I recomend you see this tutorial, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA), for a better understanding.

So, in this case you typically should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup. For example, in your scenario, I'd add a list of companies under a userId. Doing this, you'll be able to query all the companies that belong to a single user, if obviously it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the references, you're creating.
If you want to get reference to "Unverified Employees" and "Companies" nodes you should create

```
unverifiedRef = database.getReference("Unverified Employees");
companiesRef = database.getReference("Companies");
```

instead of

```
unverifiedRef = database.getReference("/Unverified Employees");
companiesRef = database.getReference("/Companies");
```

(notice missing slash **/** sign in the reference string name)

Hope this will help